# Use C++ DLL in .NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, cygwin

I asked this question yesterday about using the Cygwin compiler to produce a C++ DLL that can be used by .NET: [Using C++ app in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155237/using-c-app-in-net)

The solution was to compile the C++ application using Visual C++ rather than Cygwin i.e. I was able to call a C++ function from .NET.

Why am I able to do this in Visual C++ and not Cygwin? The code can be found in my linked question.  Here is a screen shot of Dependancy Walker for the Visual C++ DLL in case it helps answer my question:

[image]

Comment: Probably the issue relates to cygwin dependencies failing to be resolved at DLL load time. Or perhaps the cygwin DLL does not like being hosted in a managed process.

Comment: Duplicate of [Reference a GNU C (POSIX) DLL built in GCC against Cygwin, from C#/NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710465/reference-a-gnu-c-posix-dll-built-in-gcc-against-cygwin-from-c-net)  This question appears to describe a scenario identical to yours. I expect that this answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name mangling schemes are different in gcc/mingw/cygwin and msvs.  You'll have to use the pure-C interface if you want to share DLLs between compilers.

Alternatively, you could use .def files as is described in the bottom answer to this question: [How to use libraries compiled with MingW in MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529770/how-to-use-libraries-compiled-with-mingw-in-msvc)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't the screenshot I have provided show that the function name is not manged i.e. it is: hello.?

Comment: Ahh, you have two issues then, the first is that when you come from mingw, there is a name mangling problem, the second is calling unmanaged code from managed code.  The second is straightforward, but annoying.  This article is a few years old, but shows what to do:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tanmayit08/unmanaged-cpp-dll-call-from-managed-C-Sharp-application/

Comment: Thanks, your last comment says:  "there is a name mangling problem".  Doesn't the screenshot in my question show that there is not? I am new to C++ interoperability so I am obviously missing something.

Comment: You may not have that problem if it's an 'extern "C"' export from the DLL.  But if the export is a member variable or a class, there should be a problem linking against it from another family of compilers.  From your screenshot, you could certainly use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to get to 'hello'.  Personally, I try to stick to a C-style interface (rather than a C++ style interface) for DLL exports to avoid the name mangling problem.

Comment: Sorry, by C-style I mean pretty much a global function export.  by C++-style I mean an object or a member of an object.